# Is there a way to test looser airflow DAG dependencies? i.e. not direct dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have found the Apache docs quite useful for putting together airflow unit tests: https://www.restack.io/docs/airflow-knowledge-apache-unit-testing

However, rather than testing direct dependencies, is there a way to test indirect dependencies, for example:

```
task1 -> task2 -> task3 -> task4 ...
```

I want to simply test that `task4` is a downstream dependency of `task1`, regardless of how far down, as long as it is a downstream dependency somewhere. Is this possible?

Tests indirect dependency, for 'looser' unit tests.